# Where can I see the cards I'm selling on Steam?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I want to sell some cards on steam.

After i clicked on the sell buton on some cards. i am no more able to see it in any of my account/settings or any page (former .

Is there a page/place to track my "in progress" sold cards, I mean the ones i put on the market place but not yet sold.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can find your sales in progress on the [community market page](http://steamcommunity.com/market), at the top.

[image: My active listings]

Comment: @czupe This is also where you go if you decide you don't want to sell it after all.  You can just click "remove" to remove it from your list of items for sale, and it'll go back into your inventory, but ONLY if it hasn't been sold yet.